# Control the space the <br> tag gives html/css

Tags: html, css, newline

I want to create a line break in HTML 5 but control how much spacing it puts.

This is how it looks with one `<br />` tag:


[image: Picture with one br tag]

This is how it looks with two `<br />` tags:


[image: Picture with two br tags]

I want to do something like a 1.5 line break. Could you please let me know if this is possible? If so, how?

Comment: _"Type page no. here"_ is it an input field?

Comment: Yes, with `type="number"`.

Comment: What you're describing isn't a line break. Just use margin.

Comment: @ksav How would I do that?

Comment: Impossible to say given that there is no code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using CSS. Instead of using a `<br>` tag use a `<p>` element instead and give it a unique class. Then with CSS make a rule set for that class and make this declaration: `line-height: calc(1rem + .5rem)`.

You can also use margin. Whether it is `margin-top` or `margin-bottom`.

Comment: Not so sure if this would be a correct answer. First, you have a typo, which should be `height`, and second, I do not see a difference between 2 `<br />` tags and this solution. Is there any other way to do this? Because sadly, this isn't working.

Comment: @K.KDesgins Thanks for pointing the typo out I fixed it. Also, you can always change the values in the `calc()` function to make it so it is not the same size as 2 `<br>` elements.

Comment: I did; the result isn't changing. I even changed it to `line-height: calc(1rem + 5rem);`, But it does not seem to change. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @K.KDesgins I just played around with it. It worked when I inserted this (`ㅤ`) invisible character in the `<p>` element and then the `line-height` worked. So try that.

Comment: @K.KDesgins Take a look at this [site](https://example.coolprojects.repl.co/) and view the code [here](https://replit.com/@coolprojects/example?v=1#style.css)

Comment: Do you see a difference if you change the `.5` to `.1`?

Comment: @K.KDesgins I see a slight change. The easiest way to see it is to highlight the invisible character then change the line height with dev tools.

Comment: I think I fixed it. Using `margin-bottom: 0.75em;` works better for me. Do you mind changing your answer to that so I can mark it as best?

Comment: Why are you using `calc(1rem + .5rem)` instead of just `1.5rem`?

Comment: @Sean I used the `calc()` function because I was thinking 1 line plus half a line instead of just `1.5rem`. They would return the same result thought.